# 403 when copying request from chrome to curl

Tags: curl, web-scraping, scrapy

Trying to scrape a website. It was working fine about a month ago but now it gives 403 response even though the curl request was copied from chrome dev tools. The requests still work in browser and through postman.
The website is kohls.com

Comment: suggest you copy the curl from chrome, and execute it in shell, if it works, parse it in https://curl.trillworks.com/, then copy the data, params, url, and make requests with requests module in python.In this procedure, hope you will find the solution to forge the data to make a success request

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to use some proxy, looks like they really answer with 403 to some IP pools.

Comment: Changing to different proxies didn't help. The requests work fine through postman when the cookies are copied from browser.

Comment: Yes. so certain proxies do work. But I'm looking to know how the website detects i'm using curl or scrapy.

Answer (score 0):

You are being blocked by User Agent. Try setting it with the -A flag and the -L flag to follow redirects like this:

```
curl -v  -L -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0" https://kohls.com
```